# Bootstrap 3 align button text underneath GlyphIcon

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I have this code that creates some Bootstrap 3 buttons with a GlyphIcon and some text but the problem is the text is aligned right of the icon.  How can i align the text underneath the icon?

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>Archive</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>Resend</button>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the `text-center` helper class to the `.btn`, and add a `<br>` after the icon, before the text.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span><br>Resend</button>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/SWzsbPwPWC

Comment: +1 So simple and it works. I'll accept answer as soon as I can